# Spun it on me (AmE)

Tags: word-usage, usage, expressions, american-english

A group of friends is talking, and one of them says she is leaving the town for good. The rest show how sad they are and, after their affectionate words, the girl saying good-bye replies:

> Well, you have **spun** it on me. Now I'm going to cry.

I don't really know how to interpret "spun" in this context. After looking it up in some dictionaries, I'm almost certain --but not totally sure-- that it's not used in the sense of rotating or anything similar. Maybe does she mean her head starts to spin? Am I missing something obvious here?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello! On a random TV show (sorry for not being able to provide the title, but I found it just zapping). English subtitles were on, and I'm pretty certain I saw "spun" written and that she pronounced /spʌn/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Your interpretation makes all the sense put in context!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's answer-worthy if you want to include an example that you found in lyrics

Comment: It seems like there were comments here before? What answer had they given? How about that the original quote is a mistake, and should be "you sprung it on me" which means "to surprise".

Comment: "Spun it on me" is not an American English phrase. English subtitles by non-English speakers are notoriously bad.